# Sum every n elements for specific columns and take nth value of other columns [in R]

Tags: r

I am trying to sum every n elements in a data frame for specific columns.
For other columns, the nth element should be picked up.

For example, if `n=5` and dataframe is `data.frame(X=1:15,Y=1:15)`, then (let's say the first column is summed up in groups of 5 and second column is taken at nth value) result should be `X=15,40,65 and Y=5,10,15.`

The column numbers to sum are provided by a different variable (e.g., in above scenario it would contain 1). I've tried using 2 loops to handle this scenario, one for add and other for nth value, but I am then left with 2 different dataframes where order of columns is lost and code becomes inefficient. Is there a way to efficiently generate a new dataframe where column numbers present in a provided variable are added in group of n whereas others are taken at nth value? Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to specify the number of rows (and the nth) element using `tidyverse`. So, here I use `rep` to create groups for every 5 rows. Then, we can get the sum for a specific column (i.e., `X`) by group, then use `nth` to select the fifth element for the other column, `Y`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(grp = rep(row_number(), length.out = n(), each = 5)) %>% 
  summarise(X = sum(X),Y = nth(Y, 5)) %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
      X     Y
  <int> <int>
1    15     5
2    40    10
3    65    15
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(X = 1:15, Y = 1:15), 
  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

The nice thing about this approach is that we could adapt it for multiple columns for each function, as I suspect you might want to sum several columns and get the nth element of several columns. So, we can make use of `across` to specify the columns that we want to return.

```
df2 %>% 
  group_by(grp = rep(row_number(), length.out = n(), each = 5)) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(X,Z), sum), across(c(Y,A), nth, 5)) %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
      X     Z     Y     A
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    15    65     5    15
2    40    90    10    20
3    65   115    15    25
```

Data

```
df2 <- structure(list(X = 1:15, Y = 1:15, Z = 11:25, A = 11:25), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))

df2
    X  Y  Z  A
1   1  1 11 11
2   2  2 12 12
3   3  3 13 13
4   4  4 14 14
5   5  5 15 15
6   6  6 16 16
7   7  7 17 17
8   8  8 18 18
9   9  9 19 19
10 10 10 20 20
11 11 11 21 21
12 12 12 22 22
13 13 13 23 23
14 14 14 24 24
15 15 15 25 25
```

Answer (score -1):

- create a group index by "rep" function
- elements in each group need to be equal or less than your assign n
- use "[" function to truncate the group index array
- use group by function to aggregate values in each group
- use summarise_all function to do the same calculations in every columns.

```
library(dplyr)

# assign n = ?
n <- 5

# result
data.frame(X=1:15,Y=1:15) %>%
  mutate(idx = rep(1:n(), each = n)[1:n()]) %>%
  group_by(idx) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)
```